# How to update Nuget Package Manager Without Visual Studio installed?

Tags: nuget, upgrade, build-tools

There is a build server **without** Visual Studio, there are only build tools (MSBuild.exe, Nuget Manager,...). The Nuget Packet Manager need to upgraded to new version, but I cannot find any installer or way how to upgrade it without Visual Studio Gallery.

How shoudl I upgrade the Nuget Manager on build server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latest version of the nuget.exe command-line tool is always available from http://nuget.org/nuget.exe.

[More details](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/installing-nuget)

Comment: This was confusing to me. There is no nuget.exe in program files or any expected folder. The problem was solved by replacing the nuget.exe in project/.nuget directory. This means that Visual Studio build does use different nuget than msbuild. There is another nuget in project/foolproof.x.x.x./nuget.exe I didn't replaced it. What it this for?

Comment: Because they want sure that you are using correct nuget version for the specific solution. They are in this way support backward compatibility or something like that.

Comment: The exe download location has changed to: https://www.nuget.org/downloads